# Display first element of a one-to-many relationship in Flask-Admin

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I'm currently using Flask-Admin to create an admin screen but I'm running into a roadblock. Suppose I have two classes that look like this:

```
class Part(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
  part_data = db.relationship("PartHistory", backref="part")
  name = db.Column(db.String(255))

class PartHistory(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
  part_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('part.id'))
  date_checked = db.Column(db.Date)
```

Part has a one-to-many relationship on PartHistory. I'd like to create a view that shows the Part name in one column and the first date_checked in the other column. I tried something like this:

```
column_list = ("name", "part_data[0].date_checked")
```

But that doesn't seem to work. It also seems like I'm going about this the wrong way. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use [`column-property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapper_config.html#using-column-property) to define a computed column which would be populated with the field you need. Below I used a `min` value, but you can construct arbitrary query to get the first by ID (best way to achieve that would be backend-specific):

```
class Part(db.Model):
  # ...
  date_checked = db.column_property(
        db.select([db.func.min(PartHistory.date_checked)]).\
            where(PartHistory.part_id==id).\
            correlate_except(PartHistory)
    )
```

*Note that you might not be able to sort by this column though.*